# Declined flag on a comment that was fully implemented in an answer

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

Recently I flagged [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/213457/looks-prime-to-me/213504#comment500073_213504) as no longer needed, since it was fully implemented in an my answer. Furthermore, I thanked the user helped my shortening my answer.

After reading [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16230/98669), I was wondering why this flag was marked as unhelpful? Is there something else in this comment that is still relevant?

Comment: The comments do briefly explain the change that was made (e.g. from `==1` to `<2`) which would otherwise require going to the post edit history to view.

Answer (score 7):

Not the flag-marker, and I by no means represent the community's customs, rules, or attitudes, but I feel like a comment suggesting an improvement to an answer here sort of represents part of the *story* of how that program got golfed to where it is, rather than fixing some factual error or typo in the body of a question. So regardless of whether or not the flag was marked appropriately, that may at least be the rationale.

Comment: Yeah.  I marked the flag for this reason.  The comments also give you a chance to show your appreciation for a specific golf using the upvote button, which I feel is somewhat valuable.

Comment: In particular it annoys me it when comments that suggested golfing opportunities got deleted, as I'm too lazy to try to figure out what happened from the edit history.